# Applying Fourier transform property

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

From:

$g(t)\sin\left(\omega_{0}t\right)\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2j}[G(\omega-\omega_{0})-G(\omega+\omega_{0})]$

Prove that:

$G(\omega)\sin\left(\omega T\right)\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2j}[g(t+T)-g(t-T)]$

USING the time-frequency duality property:

$G(t)\Leftrightarrow 2 \pi g(-\omega)$

I'm stuck and I can't get rid of the 2pi multiplying nor the g(-w)

Thanks in advanced